# How to make Windows 10 search bar diacritic-insensitive?

Tags: windows-10, windows-search, diacritics

Typing without diacritics (in languages that use it) is often much faster/more convenient. Is there an option that allows making the search bar insensitive to diacritics?

For example, so that typing *"**ra**dek"* matches also *"**řá**dek".*

Comment: _Maybe_ the advanced region settings in control panel will allow you to change the sorting behavior. Can’t test it atm.

Comment: I got around to trying it: What you want already works for me on the "German (Germany)" locale.